# Plotting lists with different number of elements in matplotlib

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a list of numpy arrays, each potentially having a different number of elements, such as:

```
[array([55]),
 array([54]),
 array([], dtype=float64),
 array([48, 55]),]
```

I would like to plot this, where each array has an abscissa (x value) assigned, such as `[1,2,3,4]` so that the plot should show the following points: `[[1,55], [2, 54], [4, 48], [4, 55]]`.
Is there a way I can do that with matplotlib? or how can I transform the data with numpy or pandas first so that it is can be plotted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is chain the original array and generate a new array with "abscissas". There are many way to concatenated, one of the most efficient is using **itertools.chain**.

```
import itertools
from numpy import array

x = [array([55]), array([54]), array([]), array([48, 55])]

ys = list(itertools.chain(*x))
# this will be [55, 54, 48, 55]

# generate abscissas
xs = list(itertools.chain(*[[i+1]*len(x1) for i, x1 in enumerate(x)]))
```

Now you can just plot easily with matplotlib as below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(xs, ys)
```

Comment: Not really. I need the last two elements, 48 and 55 to be associated to the same abcissa (the same x) in that case 4.

Comment: If you wan to plot an individual line, I've changed the code above. Not quite sure what you're trying to plot but the above will do

Comment: This works, but to get `xs = [1, 2, 4, 4]` as requested, you need to use `[[i+1]*len(x1) for i, x1 in enumerate(x)]`. (currently, it gives `[0, 1, 3, 3]`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have different markers for different groups of data (the colours are automatically cycled by `matplotlib`):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

markers = ['o', #'circle',
           'v', #'triangle_down',
           '^', #'triangle_up',
           '<', #'triangle_left',
           '>', #'triangle_right',
           '1', #'tri_down',
           '2', #'tri_up',
           '3', #'tri_left',
           '4', #'tri_right',
           '8', #'octagon',
           's', #'square',
           'p', #'pentagon',
           'h', #'hexagon1',
           'H', #'hexagon2',
           'D', #'diamond',
           'd', #'thin_diamond'
           ]

n_markers = len(markers)

a = [10.*np.random.random(int(np.random.random()*10)) for i in xrange(n_markers)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for i, data in enumerate(a):
    xs = data.shape[0]*[i,]  # makes the abscissas list
    marker = markers[i % n_markers] # picks a valid marker
    ax.plot(xs, data, marker, label='data %d, %s'%(i, marker))

ax.set_xlim(-1, 1.4*len(a))
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
ax.legend(loc=None)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: Graph with different markers]
Notice the limits to `y` scale are hard coded, change accordingly. The `1.4*len(a)` is meant to leave room on the right side of the graph for the legend.

The example above has no point in the `x=0` (would be dark blue circles) as the randomly assigned size for its data set was zero, but you can easily place a `+1` if you don't want to use `x=0`.

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas to create a numpy array with nans inserted when an array is empty or shorter than the longest array in the list...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr_list = [np.array([55]),
            np.array([54]),
            np.array([], dtype='float64'),
            np.array([48, 55]),]

df = pd.DataFrame(arr_list)
list_len = len(df)
repeats = len(list(df))
vals = df.values.flatten()
xax = np.repeat(np.arange(list_len) + 1, repeats)
df_plot = pd.DataFrame({'xax': xax, 'vals': vals})
plt.scatter(df_plot.xax, df_plot.vals);
```

Answer (score 0):

with `x` your list :

```
[plt.plot(np.repeat(i,len(x[i])), x[i],'.') for i in range(len(x))]
plt.show()
```

Comment: Its bad practice to call a list `list`

Comment: you're right,  it was just for the sake of the example :)

Comment: Thanks, but my actual list is very large, and I don't think it will be efficient to call `plot` so many times.

Answer (score 0):

@Alessandro Mariani's answer based on itertools made me think of another way to generate an array containg the data I needed. In some cases it may be more compact. It is also based on `itertools.chain`:

```
import itertools
from numpy import array

y = [array([55]), array([54]), array([]), array([48, 55])]
x = array([1,2,3,4])
d = array(list(itertools.chain(*[itertools.product([t], n) for t, n in zip(x,y)])))
```

`d` is now the following array:

```
array([[ 1, 55],
       [ 2, 54],
       [ 4, 48],
       [ 4, 55]])
```